# is there a prop for generating always the y-tick above the max data value?

Tags: chart.js

[image of the outcome of this configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A3dV3.png)

```
            y: {
                type: 'linear',
                beginAtZero: true,
                stacked: selectedChartMode === 'stack',
                title: {
                    text: filterLabel,
                },
                ticks: {
                    precision: 1,
                    maxRotation: 0,
                    callback: (value) => {
                        return (
                            formatValue(Number(value), metrics, 1)
                        );
                    },
                },
            }
```

I'm trying to find a prop for getting always the next max 'nice' tick,

`includeBounds` - works only if you define min/max
`bounds` generate the max value as a tick but not nicely.
`maxLimitTicks` - doesn't have a consist behaviour with different data values.